# Downgrading the android emulator in Android Studio ? (v 27. only shows a blank screen)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm using Android Studio and up to now everything was fine.

With the new update the Android emulator only shows a blank screen when the app is started. This is v.27 of the emulator, and I want to go back to v.26.

So, how do you downgrade the Android emulator in Android Studio? I found out that the files are in the "platform-tools/emulator" directory of the sdk, but the files are too different to just swap them (the new emulator uses .exe for executable and .dll libraries, the old one no extension for executable and .dylib libraries)

Also, I may not have the complete version of the v.26 emulator, where can one download old versions of the emulator ?

Answer (score -1):

you don't need to do a downgrading but this issues have been solved in the 27.0.5 version of the emulator it sould solved your issues.